# What order of arrangement is recommended for on and catch?

Tags: flutter, oop, dart, try-catch

Between on and Catch which gets executed first and what order is recommended?

```
void doSomeApiCall() {
  try {
    //make http request
  } on SocketException {} catch (e) {
    //do something.
  }
}
```

should **on** come before **catch**?
Is there a recommended order or approach?
And what effect does the order have on code ?

Answer (score 2):

`on` clauses are processed in order, and the first clause that matches the type of the thrown exception will be executed.  A bare `catch` clause (i.e., without `on`) will be executed if the exception did not match any of the `on` clauses.

You don't have a choice about relative ordering between `on` and `catch`; attempting to put the `catch` clause before an `on` clause would be a syntax error.

Note that writing:

```dart
void doSomeApiCall() {
  try {
    //make http request
  } on SocketException {} catch (e) {
    //do something.
  }
}
```

is different from:

```dart
void doSomeApiCall() {
  try {
    //make http request
  } on SocketException catch (e) { // No empty block before `catch`.
    //do something.
  }
}
```

The first version catches thrown `SocketException`s but the empty block does nothing with them.  The bare `catch` clause catches all other thrown exceptions and executes the `//do something` block.

The second version executes the `//do something` block only for caught `SocketException`s, and all other exceptions will not be caught.

Also, note that [having a bare `catch` clause without `on` is discouraged](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses).

Answer (score 0):

Is not about what executes first. The correct way to catch an exception is this:

```
void doSomeApiCall() {
  try {
    //make http request
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    //do something.
  } on SomeOtherException catch (f) {
    //do something.
  }
}
```